# How to parse nested elements with the same name with HappyMapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml

I have an XML file with nested elements of the same name, specifically:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <category>
        <name>Parent category</name>
        <category>
            <name>Child category 1</name>
        </category>
        <category>
            <name>Child category 2</name>
        </category>
    </category>
</root>
```

I am using [HappyMapper gem](https://github.com/dam5s/happymapper) with this mapping:

```
class Root
    include HappyMapper
    has_many :category, Category
end

class Category
    include HappyMapper
    has_many :category, Category
end
```

Now, if I run `root = Root.parse(xml)`, I'd expect to get the whole tree as nested elements. I expect `root.category.size` to return `1` and `root.category.first.category` to return `2`.

Instead, I'm getting all elements with name `category` in root also. Is there a way how to specify that has_many is supposed to look only for direct children?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. There is an optional `xpath` parameter for `has_many` and value `"."` means it will look in direct children only.

So the solution is:

```
class Root
    include HappyMapper
    has_many :category, Category, xpath: '.'
end

class Category
    include HappyMapper
    has_many :category, Category, xpath: '.'
end
```